# Recursive query in recursive table using MySql

Tags: mysql

Good morning friends, I am stuck with a recursive query using mysql (version 8.x), I would appreciate any help you can give me.

If I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE tb__menu (
    id BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    idmenu BIGINT UNSIGNED,
    description VARCHAR(250),
    order SMALLINT UNSIGNED,
    CONSTRAINT pk_menu PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_menu_menu FOREIGN KEY (idmenu) REFERENCES tb__menu (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

And the following records:

```
id | idmenu | description | order
1  | NULL   | Master      | 1
2  | NULL   | Maintenance | 2
3  | NULL   | Transaction | 3
4  | 1      | Products    | 1
5  | 1      | Finance     | 2
6  | 2      | Persons     | 1
7  | 3      | Customers   | 1
8  | 3      | Providers   | 2
```

I need to make a query that returns a structure like the following (considering 'n' levels):

```
[
    {
        'id': 1,
        'description': 'Master',
        'children': [
            {
                'id': 4,
                'description': 'Products',
                'children': [
                ]
            },
            {
                'id': 5,
                'description': 'Finance',
                'children': [
                ]
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        'id': 2,
        'description': 'Maintenance',
        'children': [
            {
                'id': 6,
                'description': 'Persons',
                'children': [
                ]
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        'id': 3,
        'description': 'Transaction',
        'children': [
            {
                'id': 7,
                'description': 'Customers',
                'children': [
                ]
            },
            {
                'id': 8,
                'description': 'Providers',
                'children': [
                ]
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Use a [recursive CTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive)